# Algorithm for `rmarkovchain` in R

Tags: r, monte-carlo, markov-process

What method or algorithm is used in the function `rmarkovchain` from the R-package [markovchain](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markovchain/) to generate samples and how does it work?

**Edit:**

I was interested in the following part from a mathematical standpoint: `outstate <- sample(size = 1, x = markovchain@states, prob = rowProbs)`. What is the math/formula behind this statement? I'm sorry that this wasn't clear from my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an expanded version of my comment.

R's internal sample() function is implemented as per https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/random.c.  There are two methods implemented.  The first is the "classic" inversion approach- sample $U\sim$Uniform$(0,1)$ and find $k$ such that $\sum_{j< k} p_j \leq U < \sum_{j\leq k} p_j$ (using hopefully obvious notation).

As Brian Ripley reported https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2005-August/034412.html, we looked at efficient algorithms for sample() in 2005.  It is difficult to come up with a good one-size-fits all rule but as mentioned a basic rule of thumb is to use [Walker's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method) if there are more than 200 probabilities >= 0.1/n. And this is what is in the source code (the ?sample documentation says 250 but that is incorrect).

So, for the Markov chain application you mentioned, **inversion sampling would always be used**, not Walker's method.

As you've probably realised this might not be great for Markov chain (and similar) simulations where you will often take small (n=1 for Markov Chains) samples from the same, or similar, distributions.  In particular, for some transition matrices, it might be much more efficient to compute the lookup table for Walker's algorithm at the beginning.  (It also depends on how many update steps you want to do in the Markov chain etc).

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the function `rmarkovchain`, meaning you simply type `rmarkovchain`, you can spot the lines

```
for (i in 1:n) {
    sampledValues <- markovchainSequence(n = 1, markovchain = object[[1]], 
        ...)
    outIter <- rep(i, length(sampledValues))
    if (dim(object) > 1) {
        for (j in 2:dim(object)) {
          pos2take <- length(sampledValues)
          newVals <- markovchainSequence(n = 1, markovchain = object[[j]], 
            t0 = sampledValues[pos2take])
          outIter <- c(outIter, i)
          sampledValues <- c(sampledValues, newVals)
        }
    }
    iteration <- c(iteration, outIter)
    values <- c(values, sampledValues)
}
```

that are those where simulation takes place. They rely on `markovchainSequence` and if you type again `markovchainSequence`, you can see that the simulation part is

```
for (i in 1:n) {
    rowProbs <- markovchain@transitionMatrix[which(markovchain@states == 
        state), ]
    outstate <- sample(size = 1, x = markovchain@states, 
        prob = rowProbs)
    chain[i] <- outstate
    state <- outstate
}
```

which means there is nothing surprising in the way the Markov chain is simulated: given the current state (or `state`), take the row of the Markov transition matrix

```
rowProbs <- markovchain@transitionMatrix[which(markovchain@states == 
            state), ]
```

and sample (or `sample`) one state according to the probability distribution on the states defined by that row

```
outstate <- sample(size = 1, x = markovchain@states, 
            prob = rowProbs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was interested in the following part from a mathematical standpoint: `outstate <- sample(size = 1, x = markovchain@states, prob = rowProbs)`. What is the math/formula behind this statement? I'm sorry that this wasn't clear from my question.

Comment: @JimBoy `?sample`

Comment: @ssdecontrol Yes, but with `prob = rowProbs`. I wonder how one draws samples from a given distribution/transition matrix?

Comment: @JimBo `state` is always going to be length 1. So `rowProbs` it's just a single row from the matrix that gets converted to a vector inside `sample`.

This code is about as literally close as it gets to what you would do "on paper" to simulate a Markov chain: look up the transition probabilities in the row corresponding to your current state, then sample from the states accordingly. Nothing fancy at all here.

Comment: @JimBo it seems you asking about how R samples from discrete distributions generally, right?

Comment: You can browse the R source code repository to check.  When I looked at this in 2005, the default method was to invert the CDF.  I think there were some other methods too.  I implemented Walker's alias sampling algo, which might be better depending on how many steps you do in the chain and how many realisations.

Comment: https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/random.c - it is either inverting the CDF (i.e. calculate cumulative probabilities and find the last which is less than a uniform rv) or walker alias sampling.  (Although the one in the current source isn't the one I wrote)

Comment: @P.Windridge This is exactly what I was looking for! If you want to make an answer from your comment I would gladly accept it! :)

Comment: @JimBoy, thanks done, although it seems mean to deny Xi'an the answer at this point :)

Comment: @P.Windridge: no worries!